# The div in my website move when I zoom. (Even if I use em or percentage)

Tags: html, css, zooming

I know that many people ask this question, but I can't make my website work. When I zoom every div go one under the other. I post only a little part of my html css cause the problem comes also with two div.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Sans-Serif;
 background-image: url("pictures/backgroundbody.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

p {
 display: inline;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#page {
   
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#header{
 
 height: 11.937em;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0.812em;
}

#titlebar {
 height: 6.25em;
 

}

#giga_weather_and_search{
 float: right;
 margin-right: 15em;
 font-size: 0.875em;
 color: #5278ae;
 text-align: right;
 width: 27.875em;
 height: 6em;
 
}

#weather_bar{
 font-size: 0.857em;
 float: right;
}

#weather_bar td{
 padding-left: 0.357em;
 padding-right: 0.357em;
}

.weather_table{
 padding: 0.428em;
 border-spacing: 0px;
   border-collapse: separate;
}

#upper_search_bar{
 
 float: right;
 font-size: 0.857em;
}

.upper_search_table{
 padding: 0.214em;
}

#upper_search_bar td{
 padding-left: 0.143em;
 padding-right: 0.143em;
}

#bottom_search_bar{
 float: right;
 font-size: 0.857em;

}

#bottom_search_bar td{
 padding-left: 0.143em;
 padding-right: 0.143em;
}

#logo_bar{
 margin-left: 12em;
 margin-top: 4.312em;
 float: left;
 width:  23.125em;
 height: 2.375em;
 
}

#logo_bar img{
 width:  23.125em;
 height: 2.375em;
 
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>
  Colorado Breaking News, Sports, Wheather, Traffic - The Denver Post
 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
 
  <style type="text/css">
  A:link, A:visited {text-decoration: none}
     A:hover {text-decoration: underline}
  </style>
</head>



<body>
 
 <div id="page">
  <div id="header">
   <div id="titlebar">
    <div id="giga_weather_and_search">
     <div id="weather_bar">
      <table class="weather_table">
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="weather">
         <a href="">Weather: </a>
         <a href=""><img src="pictures/weather.png" alt="weather logo"></a>
         <p>Denver, CO</p> 
        </div>
       </td>
       
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <img src="pictures/barretta_weather_bar.png" alt="weather barretta">
       </td>
       
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="now">
         <a href="">Now: 39&#176;</a>
        </div>
       </td>
       
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <img src="pictures/barretta_weather_bar.png" alt="weather barretta">
       </td>
        
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="high">
         <a href="">High: 49&#176;</a>
        </div>
       </td>
       
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <img src="pictures/barretta_weather_bar.png" alt="weather barretta">
       </td>
        
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="low">
         <a href="">Low: 49&#176;</a>
        </div>
       </td>
       
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <img src="pictures/barretta_weather_bar.png" alt="weather barretta">
       </td>
        
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="forecast">
         <a href="">5-Day Forecast</a>
        </div>
       </td>    
      </table> 
     </div> <!--weather_bar-->
     
     
     <div id="upper_search_bar">
       <table class="upper_search_table">
        <td style="white-space:nowrap">
         <div class="newsletters">
          <a href="">Newsletter</a>
         </div>
        </td>
        
        <td style="white-space:nowrap">
         <img src="pictures/barretta_weather_bar.png" alt="weather barretta">
        </td>
        
        <td style="white-space:nowrap">
         <div class="subscribe">
          <a href="">Subscribe</a>
         </div>
        </td>
        
        <td style="white-space:nowrap">
         <img src="pictures/barretta_weather_bar.png" alt="weather barretta">
        </td>
        
        <td style="white-space:nowrap">
         <div class="member_services">
          <a href="">Member Services</a>
         </div>
        </td>
       </table>
     </div> <!--upper_search_bar-->
     
     <div id="search_bar">
      <img src="pictures/search_bar.png" alt="search bar"/>
     </div>
     
     <div id="bottom_search_bar">
      <table class="bottom_search_table">
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="autos">
         <a href="">Autos</a>
        </div>
       </td>
       
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <img src="pictures/barretta_bottom_search_bar2.png" alt="barretta bottom search bar">
       </td>
       
        
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="real_estate">
         <a href="">Real Estate</a>
        </div>
       </td>
       
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <img src="pictures/barretta_bottom_search_bar2.png" alt="barretta bottom search bar">
       </td>
        
       <td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="jobs">
         <a href="">Jobs</a>
        </div>
       </td>
       
      </table>
     </div> <!--bottom_search_bar-->
    </div> <!--giga_weather_and_search-->
    
    <div id="logo_bar">
     <img src="pictures/logo_bar.png"/>
    </div>
   </div> <!--titlebar-->
          </div> <!--header-->
 </div> <!--page-->
</body>
```

Comment: In the html above there are two main div: "giga_weather_and_search" and "logo_bar" . This two div move when I zoom

Comment: Ok I solved on my monitor.
I put width:   1366px; height: 100%; in the body.
Obviously if I visit my website in an other monitor (or on mobile) the website won't work correctly... Ideas?

Comment: It's not very clear from the snippet what is supposed to happen exactly. Can you provide a screenshot of what you need it to do and what happens instead?

Comment: this is what happens at zoom 100
http://postimg.org/image/8dn3e0va9/

Comment: this is what happens at zoom 150 
http://postimg.org/image/eotq43ntt/

Comment: I think it's a problem with the div "logo_bar" (the one which contains the logo The denver Post) and the div "giga_weather_and_search" (the one on the top right which contains weather search ecc).
This logo_bar has float left and giga_weather_and_search has float right.
I think that this two float operation not work together

Comment: No, that's not the problem. It's just that the logo_bar picture won't fit in the space to the left to the top bar, so it moves down to below it. Do you want the logo_bar image to resize?

Comment: By the way, the snippet didn't actually show the problem, because you didn't have the blue bar in there that the image was overlapping onto. So you need to do some more work on that. Also, you don't have any <tr>s in your table.

Comment: Yes I want the logo_bar to resize. By the way here is the snippet code show:

Zoom at 100% = 
http://postimg.org/image/vlnzbky8x/                   

Zoom at 150% = 
http://postimg.org/image/ao06wgrxd/               

Zoom at 25% = 
http://postimg.org/image/i9qn80msh/                

And here it is the original site (try to zoom in and out). I have to do a copy of this site as an exercise for university
http://www.denverpost.com/

Comment: I solved my problem setting the right width of page (it's the dive which contains the header and center it)

#page {
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 100%;
   width: 1000px;
}